# How do I get value from DatePicker(WPF) in C#?

Tags: c#, wpf, date, datepicker

I have a *DatePicker* class in my program, but how do I get an actual value, such as 19.12.2017, from it? I've tried to apply the way that is used to get the value from *DateTimePicker* in WinForms but it didn't work.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You get the selected value from the SelectedDate property of the DatePicker.

```
<DatePicker x:Name="dp" />
```

---

```
DateTime? selectedDate = dp.SelectedDate;
if(selectedDate.HasValue)
{
    string formatted = selectedDate.Value.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
}
```