# How to get date from textbox and use it for SELECT Statement

Tags: c#, sql, wpf, datepicker

I made a programm, which shows a table from my database.

The Statement looks like that:

```
string sql = ("select CCase.RefNo AS Az, EventTemplate.EventCode AS
    Vorgang from ikaros.CCase join ikaros.Event on CCase.ID =
    Event.CCaseID join ikaros.EventTemplate on Event.EventTemplateID  =
    EventTemplate.ID where EventTemplate.EventCode='IRVB' and
    Event.EventDate ='2014-07-03' order by CCase.RefNo ASC");
```

Now with

```
Event.EventDate='2014-07-03'
```

I get the table of that Date which is given in the SELECT Statement.
But I want give the user the opportunity to give a other Date in a Textbox.
The Textbox should change the Date in the Statement.

I looked here:

[Try 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10658472/datetimepicker-for-wpf-4-0)

[Try 2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/controls-and-patterns/date-picker)

But it's not the same issue which I have.
If this is a duplicate and I was just to silly to find it, please tell me.

Comment: what exactly is your problem? [parametrizing the query](https://stackoverflow.com/a/425896/1132334) so that the date can be a variable? reading a `DateTime` [from a user interface control](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41447505/1132334)?

Comment: you want to put selected date in your query from textbox or from datetimepicker?

Comment: are you using sql ado.net?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The added link in question shows your are using WPF So,

If your date is coming from `TextBox` then you should use `TextBox.Text` property to read date from user input like

```
var date = TextBox1.Text;
```

OR

If you used `DatePicker` then you can use `DatePicker.SelectedDate.Value.Date` property to read user input

```
 var date = DatePicker1.SelectedDate.Value.Date;
```

And then pass this to sql query like

```
string sql = ("select ... where EventTemplate.EventCode='IRVB' and
    Event.EventDate ='"+ date +"' order by CCase.RefNo ASC");
```

**Note:** Always use prepared statements (parameterized query) to prevent sql injection attack.

I m not sure that you are using ADO.NET but your paramterized query look like

```
string sql = ("select ... where EventTemplate.EventCode='IRVB' and
        Event.EventDate = @date order by CCase.RefNo ASC");

SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date", date);
```

Comment: Visual Studio says: "Error 1 The name 'date' does not exist in the current context Z:\programmierung\IRVB\IRVB\Form1.cs 69 286 IRVB
"

Comment: declare `var date` in same scope where your query. you are declaring varible ouside of scope thats why vs gives you error

Comment: Is the OP using WinForms?  WPF?  UWP?  Which one is this?  You're recommending code which doesn't use parameterized queries and then recommending to always use parameterized queries?  It's difficult to provide a good answer to a bad question.  The OP needs to clarify the problem.

Comment: @David, i think you didn't visit OP's added link in question. OP added all link that are of related to WPF. and before adding paramterized query codeanswer to my answer someone downvoted already.

Comment: @er-shoaib solution worked perfectly! Thank you really much u are my hero :)