# How to capture days between two datepicker

Tags: c#, wpf

I would like to use two datepicker in WPF and capture the length of days in between start date and end date, and want to incorporate the number of days in my program how do I do that?

Comment: You should break your problem down. You actually have two problems here: 1) How to get the `DateTime` value from the datepicker. 2) How to calculate the number of days between two dates.

Comment: Note in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41447505/3181933) you don't need to convert your date to a string, though you should still perform the `HasValue` check.

Comment: You are right its a two part question, do you have a simple code example?

Comment: Are the two linked questions not sufficient?

Comment: Thank you, I see the link now :)